# PHP: use $_GET in define

Tags: php, superglobals

I am trying to define a constant like in my code below for being able to easily switch between $_POST and $_GET without the need to change multiple lines.

But I get the following Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ::
>   (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in
>   /var/www/public_docs/admin/web_interface/contract.php on line 14

```
define(DEFAULT_DATA_METHOD, $_GET);   // change to $_POST if post should be used

function getData($Name, $Default = "")
/// Encapsulate data retrieval from $_GET or $_POST
{
 return (isset(DEFAULT_DATA_METHOD[$Name]) ? DEFAULT_DATA_METHOD[$Name] : $Default); <-- Line 14
}
```

Is what I want to achieve possible? And how?

Comment: Why don't you just use `$_REQUEST`, which combines `$_POST` and `$_GET`?

Comment: Which PHP version are you working with? Arrays as constants are only supported in PHP 5.6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `define` with an array. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) is very clear about it:

> **value**
>   The value of the constant; only scalar and null values are allowed. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values.

You can use an ordinary reference variable:

```
$default_data_method =& $_GET;
```

Or you could use `$_REQUEST`, which automatically merges `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: besides, a constant is supposed to be 'constant' - both $_GET & $_POST are anything but constant.

Comment: ahhh... forget about $_REQUEST... shame on me!^^

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to put the $_GET or $_POST into a constant anyway? $_GET and $_POST are super globals and can be accessed from anywhere within the code. Assigning it to a normal variable should be sufficient, no?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is actually not a good idea. Constants should be constant.

If you're not running PHP 5.6+ you can't have an array as a constant.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

If you're not running 5.6+.

You could serialize your $_POST or $_GET data in the constant, then deserialize in your function.

```
define(DEFAULT_DATA_METHOD, serialize($_GET));
```

Comment: The web site hasn't been updated to say that this is allowed in 5.6?

Comment: I guess he's assuming that he'll never change `$_GET`, just refer to it throughout the script, so it's effectively constant.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it's what I've read. Storing an array in a constant seems like a dumb idea, so it's not something I do.

Comment: @barmar this is one of the questions that we probably shouldn't answer since it's bad software engineering to do what the poster is trying to do.

Comment: @barmar Here's a reference to allowing constants to be arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: That uses the new `const` keyword. And although you can create constant arrays, the value has to be a literal or an expression containing other constants and literals. You can't use a variable like `$_GET`.